# Parse subelement by attributes (XML, Python)

Tags: python, xml

I'm having troubles parsing a xml-file and would like to ask for some help

What I want is to parse a subelement based on `locale="EN-US"` for the `Synopsis` and `Title`

Desired result would be:

- Vertigo (US)
- Description text english

I can access both subelements in a for loop or by slicing the root element...
Also stored the subelements in a list and then access the description and title from there.
Also broke the for loop after the first iteration what did work for `Synopsis` but it's far from elegant.

If somebody could help out, I would be very grateful.

```
    <VODMetadata>
        <General assetID="XYZ" WarnerID="WarnerID12345" assetName="Vertigo" version="1" provider="Warner" providerID="www.warner.com" programmeType="Movie"/>
        <MovieInfo>
            <Movie id="1159775" name="Vertigo">
                <ProductionYear>1958</ProductionYear>
                <Studio>Warner</Studio>
                <Titles>
                    <Title locale="ES-AR" type="EPG">Vertigo(ESP)</Title>
                    <Title locale="EN-US" type="EPG">Vertigo (US)</Title>
                </Titles>
                <Synopses>
                    <Synopsis locale="EN-US">
                        <Short/>
                        <Medium/>
                        <Long>Description text english</Long>
                    </Synopsis>
                    <Synopsis locale="ES-AR">
                        <Short/>
                        <Medium/>
                        <Long>Description text spanish</Long>
                    </Synopsis>
                </Synopses>
                <Genres>
                    <Genre sequence="1">Drama</Genre>
                    <Genre sequence="2">Thriller</Genre>
                    <Genre sequence="3">Mystery</Genre>
                </Genres>
        </MovieInfo>
    </VODMetadata>
```

Comment: Share your current code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ''' <VODMetadata>
        <General assetID="XYZ" WarnerID="WarnerID12345" assetName="Vertigo" version="1" provider="Warner" providerID="www.warner.com" programmeType="Movie"/>
        <MovieInfo>
            <Movie id="1159775" name="Vertigo">
                <ProductionYear>1958</ProductionYear>
                <Studio>Warner</Studio>
                <Titles>
                    <Title locale="ES-AR" type="EPG">Vertigo(ESP)</Title>
                    <Title locale="EN-US" type="EPG">Vertigo (US)</Title>
                </Titles>
                <Synopses>
                    <Synopsis locale="EN-US">
                        <Short/>
                        <Medium/>
                        <Long>Description text english</Long>
                    </Synopsis>
                    <Synopsis locale="ES-AR">
                        <Short/>
                        <Medium/>
                        <Long>Description text spanish</Long>
                    </Synopsis>
                </Synopses>
                <Genres>
                    <Genre sequence="1">Drama</Genre>
                    <Genre sequence="2">Thriller</Genre>
                    <Genre sequence="3">Mystery</Genre>
                </Genres>
            </Movie>
        </MovieInfo>
    </VODMetadata>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.find('.//Title[@locale="EN-US"]').text)
print(root.find('.//Synopsis[@locale="EN-US"]').find('Long').text)
```

output

```
Vertigo (US)
Description text english
```